# Bokeh python callback to highlight selections/ remake data source

Tags: bokeh

I'm just getting started with Bokeh, and haven't been able to find direct examples of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Here is what I have so far:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.io import curdoc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Point data.
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(5, 2)), columns=list('XY'),
                  index=['A','B','C','D','E'])

#Line data.
def linecoordinates(ar):
    return [i+ar for i in range(0,5)]
Ldf=pd.DataFrame()
Ldf["Xs"]=df['X'].apply(lambda p: linecoordinates(p))
Ldf["Ys"]=df['Y'].apply(lambda p: linecoordinates(p))


#Plotting points.
pointchart=figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=500, tools='lasso_select',
                  title="Point scatter")
pointchart_source= ColumnDataSource(df)
pointchart.circle("X","Y",source=pointchart_source)


#1. A way to plot the lines.
Lchart1=figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=500, title="By iterating through DF rows")
for r in Ldf.index:
    Lchart1.line(Ldf.loc[r,"Xs"], Ldf.loc[r,"Ys"])


#2. Can't use stored arrays as source.
Lchart2=figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=500, title="Can't get arrays from source")
Lchart2_source= ColumnDataSource(Ldf)
Lchart2.line("Xs", "Ys", source= Lchart2_source)



layout= row(pointchart,Lchart1, Lchart2)
show(layout)



#bokeh serve --show TestApp.py
```

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Create a data source for a line chart that will have the usual interactivity functions that `source` usually offers. In the code example above, I can make a line chart by passing the lists of X/Y coordinates to the chart by iterating over the pandas dataframe. The last part of the code shows the line chart that I can't get to work because I'm probably not passing the lists of coordinates to the line chart correctly.
2. I want to demonstrate how to use a Python callback to highlight lines on the line chart by doing a Lasso Select of the points on the point chart. The point and line data sources would have the same indexes.
3. I want to demonstrate how to use a Python callback to populate a line chart from the lasso selections in the point chart. The points in the scatter have the same index as the line data that was generated in advance.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please provide more detail. It's really unclear what the format and contents of your dataframe is. Dataframe columns have to all be the same length (just like a Bokeh CDS) so it does not make sense that one column is a concatenated string of coordinates and other columns are not. In any case the answer is almost certainly that you should unpack or transform these strings much earlier and make sure the real numeric column is what is present in the dataframe (Data cleaning/preparation is typically the *first* step)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Here is the problem as it is right now. `df=pd.DataFrame({'X_Coord': {'Line_1': [1,2,3,4], 'Line_2': [11,12,13,14,15]}, 'Y_Coord': {'Line_1': [10,20,30,40], 'Line_2': [21,22,23,24,25]}})`  So that's what the dataframe lookes like. `figure=figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=500)`  `source=ColumnDataSource(data=df)`  `figure.line("X_Coord","Y_Coord", source=source)` `show(figure)` Empty chart shows up.

Comment: If you pass the individual arrays into the `.line` function, it works. I thought that I could cram the lists into the pandas dataframe and plot them as lines using ColumnDataSource. It looks like you can't do that. Is there a better way to build one data source and use it for a scatter chart and a line chart where a selection on the scatter would highlight the selections on the line chart? I thought that the key to this functionality was having a single data source.

Comment: Sorry I really don't understand. The dataframe in the comment does not have any CSV strings like the question at all. Where do they come from? Why do they exist? Are you trying to plot multi lines? That's the only sense which linked selection would make much sense.

Comment: I took your advice and prepared the data as much as possible before it's plotted. The CSV strings are now the lists in the Dataframe. The lists in the data frame can be used to make two regular lines because the list of X and Y values is given for each line. The problem is that you can't pass the lists from the `source` to the `.line` this way to plot two lines in a chart.

Comment: A CDS can certainly contain columns used to plot multiple lines, but `line` only plots one at a time. So you would either need to: 1) make multiple calls to `line`, one for each line you want to plot, or 2) rearrange your data for use with `multi_line`: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#multiple-lines But it's really not clear what you are trying to accomplish so it's hard to say what is more appropriate. It also would be more helpful if you edit your actual question with the new information with proper code formatting instead of putting lots of code in comments

Comment: Specifically: I can imagine all kinds of linked behaviours between scatters and lines. I have no idea what you have in mind is. You need to describe the interaction you want to achieve in much more detail (in the question, not in more comments)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question about how to pass lists from a `ColumnDataSource` to plot lines, but there is likely another better way. Here is an example that accomplishes points 2 and 3 from above.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.io import curdoc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(5, 2)), columns=list('XY'),index=['A','B','C','D','E'])


#Plotting points on first chart.
pointchart=figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools='lasso_select',title="Point scatter")
pointchart_source= ColumnDataSource(df)
pointchart_glyph= pointchart.circle("X","Y",source=pointchart_source)

#Making point plot with same source.
linkedpointchart=figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, title="Point scatter_LinkedSource")
linkedpointchart.circle("X","Y",source=pointchart_source)


#Making plot populated by updated source.
newplot=figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, title="Point scatter New Source via Callback")
newdatasource= ColumnDataSource(df) 
pglyph = newplot.circle(x='X', y='Y', source=newdatasource)


def newsourcecallback(attr, old, new):
        indexvalues =list(pointchart_source.data['index'][new])
        newdataframe= df.loc[indexvalues,:]
        newsource=ColumnDataSource(newdataframe[["X","Y"]])
        pglyph.data_source.data=newsource.data
        print(indexvalues)

pointchart_glyph.data_source.selected.on_change('indices',newsourcecallback) 


layout= row(pointchart,linkedpointchart,newplot)
show(layout)


curdoc().add_root(row(pointchart,linkedpointchart,newplot))


#bokeh serve --show Callback_workingExample.py
```